# I need some help in Pivot in PL/SQL

Tags: pivot

I have a table that looks like this  :

```
ELEMENTID   ELEMENTTYPE ELEMENTVALUE1   ELEMENTVALUE2
45271       ADD1        SUITE 400       SUITE40
45271       ADD2        169 LINCOLN 14  FURNACE
45271       CITY        SHARON          SHARON
45271       USCOUNTY    NORFOLK         NORFOLK
45271       STATE       MA              MA
45271       ZIP         2067            2067
```

The table has many columns like `ELEMENTVALUE1, ELEMENTVALUE2...`

Through a  PL/SQL Stored Procedure I would like to transpose all of those like this :

```
ELEMENTID   ADD1        ADD2        CITY    USCOUNTY STATE  ZIP
45271       SUITE 400   169 LINCOLN SHARON  NORFOLK  MA    2067
45271       SUITE 40    14 FURNACE  SHARON  NORFOLK  MA    2067
```

I 'm only able to get :

```
ELEMENTID   ADD1        ADD2        CITY    USCOUNTY STATE  ZIP
45271       SUITE 400   169 LINCOLN SHARON  NORFOLK  MA     2067
```

Comment: *I'm only able to get this:* will you share that what you did to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this, in this example you will need many union all depends on your number of ELEMENTVALUES

```
SELECT
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ZIP' THEN elementvalue1 END) ZIP,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ADD1' THEN elementvalue1 END) ADD1,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ADD2' THEN elementvalue1 END) ADD2,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'CITY' THEN elementvalue1 END) CITY,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'USCOUNTY' THEN elementvalue1 END) USCOUNTY,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'STATE' THEN elementvalue1 END) STATE
FROM PIVOTED
GROUP BY elementid

UNION ALL

SELECT
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ZIP' THEN elementvalue2 END) ZIP,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ADD1' THEN elementvalue2 END) ADD1,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'ADD2' THEN elementvalue2 END) ADD2,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'CITY' THEN elementvalue2 END) CITY,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'USCOUNTY' THEN elementvalue2 END) USCOUNTY,
MIN (CASE elementtype  WHEN 'STATE' THEN elementvalue2 END) STATE
FROM PIVOTED
GROUP BY elementid
```